# Why would movw di, [ebp+4] be illegal?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to compile a 6502-based emulator for an Intel Atom system, but I get these sorts of errors for this file: https://github.com/littlefluffytoys/Beebdroid/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/6502asm_x86.S

```
jni/6502asm_x86.S:163:5: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'movb'
movb ch, [ ebp+9] # ch = r10 = S
^~~~
jni/6502asm_x86.S:181:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'pushw'
pushw 0xfffa
^~~~~
```

Is this a 32/64 bit issue? I'm familiar with assembly, but not x86 or x86_64, and I'm finding it hard to track down what's going on. I understand that movq wouldn't be available on 32 bit, but I can't think why byte wouldn't be available at all.

I had to remove all the % signs from the file - seems my version of cc (4.8.4) didn't like them - but then ran into this mov issue.

What's particularly confusing is that earlier instances of movw and movb aren't producing errors, like

```
    movw  di,  [ ebp+4]     #  di = r6  = PC
    movb  cl,  [ ebp+6]     #  cl = r7  = A
```

(Although I notice these are in macro definitions, so perhaps they're not parsed yet)

I read in some Intel documentation that mov sometimes looks as follows, but I don't know enough about this format to try rewriting the dozens of errors:

```
MOV     ECX, dword ptr table[RBX][RDI]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Assembler macros are purely text substitutions.  If you don't use a macro, its contents don't have to be valid.  Anyway, this looks like trying to use AT&T operand-size suffixes in `.intel_syntax noprefix`  mode.  Maybe it worked with some assemblers?  Are you building this on a Mac (using clang's built-in assembler?)  Or maybe it was only tested that way on a Mac, and GNU binutils `as` (as invoked by GCC) is rejecting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assembler macros are purely text substitutions.  If you don't use a macro, its contents don't have to be valid.  And if it is used, it's only assembled at the place where it's used.  (It's not like an inline function, it's like a C preprocessor macro).

---

The original file uses `.intel_syntax noprefix` at the top, but then  is full of insane code like
`mov  %ebx, [%ebx + %eax*4]` and `movb %al,[%esi+%edi]` that still decorates register names with `%` despite `noprefix`, and more importantly still uses AT&T-style operand-size suffixes.

**It's a mutant hybrid of Intel and AT&T syntax, no wonder some assemblers reject it.**

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info vs. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info

On my Linux desktop, the original file assembles just fine with GNU Binutils `as`, which I invoke `gcc -m32 -c 6502asm_x86.S`.  (I'm on Linux, so this is real GCC, specifically `gcc --version` says `gcc (GCC) 9.1.0    Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` etc.  It uses `as`.  `as --version` says "GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.32")

I suspect you're on a Mac with Apple Clang.  Your "cc (4.8.4)" looks more like a gcc version number, but GCC doesn't contain an assembler.  It always uses an external one.  And on a Mac, that may still be Clang/LLVM, not GNU Binutils.

On my Linux desktop, **clang 8.0.1 rejects this file**.  It's much stricter about not accepting AT&T-isms in Intel mode, and doesn't support `.intel_syntax prefix` at all, only `intel noprefix` or `att prefix`.  After removing all the `%` characters in the file, `clang -m32 -c 6502asm_x86.S` gives the same error messages you showed:

```
6502asm_x86.S:121:5: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'movw'
    movw di, [ebp+4] # di = r6 = PC
    ^~~~
```

---

#### Fixing this mess:

If possible, use `as` aka `gas` from GNU binutils.  But IDK if it supports MachO object files so that might not be an option for you.  (Update: apparently you're on Linux trying to use an Android toolchain.  That's also clang, but probably is creating ELF objects.  So you could probably just use `as` manually.)

To actually fix the source, remove all the operand-size suffixes, too, and let the register operand(s) imply the size.

That file does correctly use GAS `.intel_syntax` operand-size overrides in cases like `mov dword ptr [ebp+20], 0` when neither operand is a register so it needs the `dword ptr`.

But you can't just remove the last character of every mnemonic: some instructions already omit it.  (It looks like that file does so for dword operand-size, but redundantly specifies it for every instruction using byte or word operand-size.)

**There are a few instructions that can still use (and sometimes need) a size suffix in Intel syntax**, for example `pushw  immediate`.  Some assemblers like NASM use `push word 123`, but GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` uses `pushw 123`.  If there's a register or memory operand, though, that can imply the size.  e.g. `push di` is a word push, `pop word ptr [ecx]` is a word pop.  You also have suffixes on "string" instructions like [`movsb/w/d`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq) / `lodsb/w/d`, and so on.

e.g.

```
do_interrupt:
        PUSHWORD di                     # push(cpu->pc)
        movzx eax, byte ptr [ebp+10]
        or  eax, 0x20           # uint8_t temp = cpu->p | 0x20;
        PUSH_BYTE al             # push(temp);
        popw ax
        movw di, [esi+eax]              # cpu->pc=*(uint16_t*)&(cpu->mem[0xfffe]);
        or byte ptr [ebp+10], 4         # cpu->p |= FLAG_I;
        movw [ebp+4],di            # Remove when C-only
        movb [ebp+9],ch             # Remove when C-only
        pop eax
        add eax,7                           # c += 7;
        push eax
```

becomes

```
do_interrupt:
        PUSHWORD di                     # push(cpu->pc)
        movzx eax, byte ptr [ebp+10]
        or    eax, 0x20           # uint8_t temp = cpu->p | 0x20;
        PUSH_BYTE al             # push(temp);
        pop   ax
        mov   di, [esi+eax]              # cpu->pc=*(uint16_t*)&(cpu->mem[0xfffe]);
        or    byte ptr [ebp+10], 4         # cpu->p |= FLAG_I;
        mov   [ebp+4],di            # Remove when C-only
        mov   [ebp+9],ch             # Remove when C-only

        # pop eax; add eax,7 ; push eax   # optimize into one instruction:
        add   dword ptr [esp], 7     # c += 7;
        # or address it relative to EBP if we know where ESP is relative to EBP
```

Obviously you'll need to look at the macro defs too.

---

This doesn't look like the most efficient code ever; could do more in registers.  But that's beside the point.  I only saw one small peephole optimization of pop/add/push into a memory-destination add, didn't try to optimize the rest.

There's other obvious stuff like

```
    movb %dl,  [%ebp+7]     #  dl = r8  = X
    movb %dh,  [%ebp+8]     #  dh = r9  = Y
```

which could be a single word load into DX = DH:DL (x86 is little-endian and has very efficient unaligned loads, if this happens to be unaligned).

So I wouldn't recommend using this code as an example to learn x86!

Comment: Thanks, that looks really helpful! It's probably the original author on a Mac: I'm looking to make this compile on my out-of-date Ubuntu laptop, to get the : key working from my Bluetooth keyboard into the emulated host running on my Android tablet, not making it more efficient or learning x86. :)  I'd use the original .so file from the APK, but it has a text relocation that Android prohibits in apps built after version 21 for security.

Comment: Maybe some of the inefficiency - like the movb pair you cite above - could be because the x86 was a direct translation from ARM?

Comment: @android.weasel: It works fine for me on Arch Linux, but I haven't tried with an older GAS.  I assumed you were on a Mac because Apple uses clang instead of GCC and GNU Binutils.  It will *not* build with clang.

Comment: It's building with AndroidNDK, which... `/home/tim/lib/android-sdk-linux/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang` is `Android (5220042 based on r346389c) clang version 8.0.7 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang b55f2d4ebfd35bf643d27dbca1bb228957008617) (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm 3c393fe7a7e13b0fba4ac75a01aa683d7a5b11cd) (based on LLVM 8.0.7svn)`. What precludes clang so completely? I've tried removing the 'w' and 'b' suffixes, but there's a couple of 'pushw 0' in WRITEBYTED that look like they'd need width qualifiers.

Comment: @android.weasel: Clang's built-in assembler in Intel-syntax mode does not accept `%eax` as a register name, or `movw` as a synonym for `mov`.  (See [How to set gcc to use intel syntax permanently?](//stackoverflow.com/a/58154963) for an example (using inline asm in C, but same problem).)   GAS does.  Oh, and yes `pushw` is an Intel mnemonic; a few instructions *do* use suffixes in Intel syntax.  I'll update my answer for that.

Comment: This is really helpful! It's assembling now. One (hopefully) last thing: the main reason I'm trying to assemble this is because the .so from the original package needs text relocation, now prohibited. I presume this relates to the error I'm currently seeing from the NDK: `shared library text segment is not shareable` - I've tried adding fPIC to the CFLAGS but the message persists. The last fns_asm part of the .S file looks like a lookup table to dispatch opcodes; I presume this is the relocation problem. I don't suppose I could just cook that into a C array of method pointers?

Comment: @android.weasel: `-fPIC` is a compile-time code-gen option.  It affects translation from C to asm.  It can't affect asm source; the human that writes the asm has to make it position-independent manually.

Comment: @android.weasel: to actually fix it, instead of a table of absolute addresses, consider using a table of relative offsets that you add to a known address. e.g. have a look at what GCC does when create jump tables for `switch`  with `-fPIE` https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84011 even on x86-64 ELF/Linux where text relocations *are* allowed.  Note that PIC/PIE in 32-bit code is generally inefficient because you don't have RIP-relative addressing modes.  Every `mov reg, [symbol]` uses an absolute address.  (related: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427))